# is there any way to get access to usage metrics data for a power bi report?

Tags: powerbi

I want to include usage metrics stats in my current report. Power bi gives a usage metric report but instead of a separate report (generated by power bi) i would like to add these metrics in the corresponding report (report whose usage metrics needs to be displayed). To do this i need to get access to usage metrics data, how do i get this data?

Initially i tried to save the Usage Metric report generated by Power Bi, hoping it will create a dataset which i will then access in my existing report.
but it does not create any dataset :(